# FitNesse throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, fitnesse

I have downloaded fitnesse-standalone.jar, and tried to run using below command

java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar

Unfortunately I am getting below exception,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin>java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar
Mar 18, 2014 4:16:54 PM fitnesse.ConfigurationParameter loadProperties
INFO: No configuration file found (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\p
lugins.properties)
root page: fitnesse.wiki.fs.FileSystemPage at ./FitNesseRoot
logger: none
authenticator: fitnesse.authentication.PromiscuousAuthenticator
page factory: fitnesse.html.template.PageFactory
page theme: fitnesse_straight
Starting FitNesse on port: 80
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\FitNesseRoot\updateL
ist (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
        at fitnesse.updates.FileUpdate.copyResource(FileUpdate.java:45)
        at fitnesse.updates.FileUpdate.doUpdate(FileUpdate.java:31)
        at fitnesse.updates.UpdaterImplementation.getUpdateFilesFromJarFile(Upda
terImplementation.java:71)
        at fitnesse.updates.UpdaterImplementation.createUpdateAndDoNotCopyOverLi
sts(UpdaterImplementation.java:62)
        at fitnesse.updates.UpdaterImplementation.<init>(UpdaterImplementation.j
ava:21)
        at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.update(FitNesseMain.java:66)
        at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.launchFitNesse(FitNesseMain.java:59)
        at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.launchFitNesse(FitNesseMain.java:48)
        at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.main(FitNesseMain.java:32)
```

Please help!

Regards
Rajib

Comment: I tried in Windows 7 64 bit OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point to the directory where the fitnesse-standalone jar is located in. Also, there's is a good chance that port 80 is already being used. Therefore, try using a different port using the -p option in that case.

Example: -jar C:/fitnesse-standalone.jar -p 8081

Answer (score 0):

You may want  to run `java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar` from the directory where you copied a file fitnesse-standalone.jar.

To avoid an error of running java you need to add java folder to the environment variables.